# What conditions result in an opened, nonblocking named pipe (fifo) being "unavailable" for reads?

Tags: python, linux, named-pipes, fifo, mkfifo

Situation:

```
new_pipe = os.open(pipe_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK) # pipe_path points to a FIFO
data = os.read(new_pipe, 1024)
```

The read occasionally raises errno -11: Resource temporarily unavailable.

When is this error raised? It seems very rare, as the common cases return data:

- If no writer has the pipe opened, empty str ('') is returned.
- If the  writer has the pipe opened, but no data is in the fifo, empty str
  ('') is also returned
- And of course if the writer puts data in the fifo, that data will be read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sendto : Resource temporarily unavailable (errno 11)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737493/sendto-resource-temporarily-unavailable-errno-11)

Comment: @agf: The other question is about a sendto erroring, which happens because the send buffer is full. The connection to this particular question is questionable at best, as we are talking about reading Unix pipes here

Comment: @NiklasB. The question certainly isn't similar, but the answer is. Voting to close as a duplicate was just a convenient way to link to the other question. and get it linked at the top of the sidebar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [POSIX specification of the `read` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) (emphasis mine):

> When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO:
>
> - If no process has the pipe open for writing, read() shall return 0 to
>     indicate end-of-file.
> - **If some process has the pipe open for writing and O_NONBLOCK is set,
>     read() shall return -1 and set errno to [EAGAIN].**

So basically your second assumption is wrong:

> If the writer has the pipe opened, but no data is in the fifo, empty str ('') is also returned

This would be against the specification and I can't reproduce that behaviour on my machine (it raises `EAGAIN` for me). This is not a big problem however, you can just catch the exception and retry:

```
import errno

def safe_read(fd, size=1024):
   ''' reads data from a pipe and returns `None` on EAGAIN '''
   try:
      return os.read(fd, size)
   except OSError, exc:
      if exc.errno == errno.EAGAIN:
         return None
      raise
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like I actually had errors in my own test code!