# How to read named FIFO non-blockingly?

Tags: python, nonblocking, fifo

I create a FIFO, and periodically open it in read-only and non-blockingly mode from a.py:

```
os.mkfifo(cs_cmd_fifo_file, 0777)
io = os.open(fifo, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
buffer = os.read(io, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

From b.py, open the fifo for writing:

```
out = open(fifo, 'w')
out.write('sth')
```

Then a.py will raise an error:

```
buffer = os.read(io, BUFFER_SIZE)

OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What conditions result in an opened, nonblocking named pipe (fifo) being "unavailable" for reads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021759/what-conditions-result-in-an-opened-nonblocking-named-pipe-fifo-being-unavai) However, this question is definitely still useful, since it's unique phrasing meant it was the first one I found on Google.

Comment: `NameError: name 'fifo' is not defined` could you please fix the example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the manpage of `read(2)`:

> ```
>    EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK
>           The  file  descriptor  fd refers to a socket and has been marked
>           nonblocking   (O_NONBLOCK),   and   the   read   would    block.
>           POSIX.1-2001  allows  either error to be returned for this case,
>           and does not require these constants to have the same value,  so
>           a portable application should check for both possibilities.
> ```

So what you're getting is that there is no data available for reading. It is safe to handle the error like this:

```
try:
    buffer = os.read(io, BUFFER_SIZE)
except OSError as err:
    if err.errno == errno.EAGAIN or err.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
        buffer = None
    else:
        raise  # something else has happened -- better reraise

if buffer is None: 
    # nothing was received -- do something else
else:
    # buffer contains some received data -- do something with it
```

Make sure you have the errno module imported: `import errno`.

Comment: after try it out, a.py raise: 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'buffer' referenced before assignment

Comment: @chaonin I tried to guess what the reason is (I did not use buffer before), and updated my example. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: io = os.open(fifo, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)

try:

 buffer = os.read(io, BUFFER_SIZE)

except OSError as err:

    if err.errno == errno.EAGAIN or err.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:

        pass

    else:

        raise err

jobs_infile = shlex.split(buffer)

os.close(io)

Comment: For interest: EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK both indicate effectively the same thing. In fact on some systems they are the same value. Checking both is a good idea though.

Comment: @lxs In fact, you have to if you want to be portable, as the read(2) manpage suggests. It's inconvenient and in python3.3, we would catch [``BlockingIOError``](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BlockingIOError) instead (which also tells us how many characters were written).

Answer (score -2):

```
out = open(fifo, 'w')
```

Who will close it for you?
Replace your open+write by this:

```
with open(fifo, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('sth')
```

**UPD:**
Ok, than just make this:

```
out = os.open(fifo, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_WRONLY)
os.write(out, 'tetet')
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, nor is it relevant considering that the code given is obviously snippetly. (-1)

Comment: If your edit was intended to address my complaint, it didn't.