# Reading, re-opening a named PIPE in a non-blocking fashion

Tags: python, python-multithreading, named-pipes

On linux, with Python 3.8 I'm trying to process text data line by line read from a named pipe (created with `mkfifo`). The reading takes place on a thread (main thread runs an `asyncio` event loop).

Problem is that the below code blocks at `open()` indefinitely when the other process - that sends the data - is not running, however I need to stop the thread when there is no data coming from the pipe after a certain amount of time.

Initally I tried with `select.select()` before I realised that it blocks at the `open()`, not at `readline()`. Then I tried with `signal.signal` setting an `alarm`, but signalling only works in the main thread, this should run in a thread pool. The best thing would be either to make the `open()` non blocking somehow, or before `open()` detect whether the other half of the pipe is open, also in a non-blocking fashion.

```py
while True:
    with open(pipe_file_path, 'r') as pipe_file:
        _log.debug("Reading log")
        while True:
            line = pipe_file.readline(768)
            if line == '':
                break
            process_line(line.rstrip()) # arbitrary processing
    _log.debug("Pipe closed")
```

The whole thing is in an endless loop (1st line), since I want to re-open the pipe immediately when the other process closes it briefly (sometimes that happens), e.g. when it re-parses its configuration. So the ultimate goal is: try to read from the pipe when it can be opened within T time, otherwise stop waiting.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345816/how-to-read-named-fifo-non-blockingly

Comment: @Barmar thank you, `fd = os.open(pipe_file_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)` then `os.read(fd)` does the trick. I'll try to experiment with `select.poll()` as well.