# What can cause a “Resource temporarily unavailable” on sock send() command

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

What can cause a `Resource temporarily unavailable` error on a socket `send()` command? The socket is setup as `AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM`. It works most of the time, but occasionally gets this error. The receiving end of the socket appears to be working properly.

I know this isn't very detailed, but I'm just looking for general ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Is this related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737493/sendto-resource-temporarily-unavailable-errno-11

Comment: Are you setting your socket to O_NONBLOCK ?

Comment: I don't think it is related to that post. My sockets are SOCK_STREAM which I believe are blocking which is what I want.

Comment: Whether a stream is blocking or non-blocking is independent of whether it's SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM. The answer there is relevant.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`"Resource temporarily unavailable"` is the error message corresponding to `EAGAIN`, which means that the operation would have blocked but nonblocking operation was requested.  For `send()`, that could be due to any of:

- explicitly marking the file descriptor as nonblocking with `fcntl()`; or
- passing the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag to `send()`; or
- setting a send timeout with the `SO_SNDTIMEO` socket option.

Comment: The cause of my problem was setting the send timeout. Thank you for you help!

Comment: @caf, In my case, different MTU size configuration in two side was causing sctp association Txqueue to be overflown when high rate of packet exchange was happening.

Making the MTU same on both system made the problem go away.
But can anyone please explain what is the reason behind the problem?

Comment: Why does setting SO_SNDTIMEO cause the error to happen? How to use that flag correctly?

Comment: @GabrielFernandez: Because this is what `SO_SNDTIMEO` requests: that the send not block for longer than the timeout period.  If the send hasn't completed and the timeout expires, it returns `EAGAIN` to indicate this condition.  How you handle that is up to your application, bearing in mind that the data you tried to send has not been sent.

Answer (score 59):

That's because you're using a `non-blocking` socket and the output buffer is full.

From the `send()` man page

```
   When the message does not fit into  the  send  buffer  of  the  socket,
   send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in non-block-
   ing I/O mode.  In non-blocking mode it  would  return  EAGAIN  in  this
   case.
```

**EAGAIN** is the error code tied to **"Resource temporarily unavailable"**

Consider using `select()` to get a better control of this behaviours

Comment: @giroy: but not actually right... actually a *blocking* socket, with `SO_SNDTIMEO`

Comment: Cool but how can we use other connection to manage simultaneous read in the DB?

Answer (score 18):

Let'e me give an example:

1. client connect to server, and send 1MB data to server every 1 second.
2. server side accept a connection, and then sleep 20 second, without recv msg from client.So the `tcp send buffer` in the client side will be full.

**Code in client side:**

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define exit_if(r, ...)                                                                          \
    if (r) {                                                                                     \
        printf(__VA_ARGS__);                                                                     \
        printf("%s:%d error no: %d error msg %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno)); \
        exit(1);                                                                                 \
    }

void setNonBlock(int fd) {
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    exit_if(flags < 0, "fcntl failed");
    int r = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    exit_if(r < 0, "fcntl failed");
}

void test_full_sock_buf_1(){
    short port = 8000;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    exit_if(fd<0, "create socket error");

    int ret = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    exit_if(ret<0, "connect to server error");
    setNonBlock(fd);

    printf("connect to server success");

    const int LEN = 1024 * 1000;
    char msg[LEN];  // 1MB data
    memset(msg, 'a', LEN);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        int len = send(fd, msg, LEN, 0);
        printf("send: %d, erron: %d, %s \n", len, errno, strerror(errno));
        sleep(1);
    }

}

int main(){
    test_full_sock_buf_1();

    return 0;
}
```

**Code in server side:**

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define exit_if(r, ...)                                                                          \
        if (r) {                                                                                     \
            printf(__VA_ARGS__);                                                                     \
            printf("%s:%d error no: %d error msg %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, errno, strerror(errno)); \
            exit(1);                                                                                 \
        }
void test_full_sock_buf_1(){

    int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    exit_if(listenfd<0, "create socket error");

    short port = 8000;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int r = ::bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    exit_if(r<0, "bind socket error");

    r = listen(listenfd, 100);
    exit_if(r<0, "listen socket error");

    struct sockaddr_in raddr;
    socklen_t rsz = sizeof(raddr);
    int cfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &raddr, &rsz);
    exit_if(cfd<0, "accept socket error");

    sockaddr_in peer;
    socklen_t alen = sizeof(peer);
    getpeername(cfd, (sockaddr *) &peer, &alen);

    printf("accept a connection from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr), ntohs(peer.sin_port));

    printf("but now I will sleep 15 second, then exit");
    sleep(15);
}
```

**Start server side, then start client side.**

**server side may output:**

```
accept a connection from 127.0.0.1:35764
but now I will sleep 15 second, then exit
Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

**client side may output:**

```
connect to server successsend: 1024000, erron: 0, Success 
send: 1024000, erron: 0, Success 
send: 1024000, erron: 0, Success 
send: 552190, erron: 0, Success 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 11, Resource temporarily unavailable 
send: -1, erron: 104, Connection reset by peer 
send: -1, erron: 32, Broken pipe 
send: -1, erron: 32, Broken pipe 
send: -1, erron: 32, Broken pipe 
send: -1, erron: 32, Broken pipe 
send: -1, erron: 32, Broken pipe
```

[image]

You can see, as the server side doesn't recv the data from client, so when the client side `tcp buffer` get full, but you still send data, so you may get `Resource temporarily unavailable` error.

Answer (score 0):

There are another case can cause error 11 `Resource temporarily unavailable`

By default, if application layer protocol is http, after first http response recv successfully, tcp connection won't be close, call recv again will be blocked and -1 will returned from recv when SO_RCVTIMEO expired, errno will be set `11`