# Program termination does not return back to bash

Tags: linux, bash, process

Recently, I asked a question but got down votes since guys thought it is not clear. However, I have found a hint which needs some digging...

There is a command line program called `fluent`. Problem is that in the Rocks, when I run it on the front-end and enter `exit`, it will return to the command prompt.

```
    5991 nodes, binary.
    5991 node flags, binary.
Done.

> exit
mahmood@cluster:~$
```

However, when I run the same command (the application is on `/export/` which is a *NFS* drive) on the compute node via `ssh`, it doesn't return to the command prompt.

```
    5991 nodes, binary.
    5991 node flags, binary.
Done.

> exit
^C^C^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 /share/apps/fluent/bin/fluent 3d -g -t4 -i elbow.journal
mahmood@compute-0-3:~$ pkill fluent*
mahmood@compute-0-3:~$ fg
/share/apps/fluent/bin/fluent 3d -g -t4 -i elbow.journal
Terminated
```

As suggested, I tried with `strace` and attached it to the process multiple times since the application runs on multicores. In one attempt, the application returned back to the terminal. I noticed that in in the last lines of the `strace`, there is a difference between the outcome of `futex`.

In the correct execution, I see:

```
    socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 12
    setsockopt(12, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
    setsockopt(12, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
    setsockopt(12, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [65536], 4) = 0
    setsockopt(12, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [65536], 4) = 0
    fcntl(12, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
    fcntl(12, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)              = 0
    connect(12, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(45470), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.10.10.251")}, 16) = 0
    write(12, "12345\0", 6)                 = 6
    write(12, "15  NORMAL_EXITING\0", 19)   = 19
    read(12, "\0", 1)                       = 1
    close(12)                               = 0
    futex(0x2b66afe5d9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 12432, NULL) = 0
    futex(0x2b66afc5c9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 12427, NULL) = 0
    close(6)                                = 0
    close(7)                                = 0
    close(8)                                = 0
    close(9)                                = 0
    close(10)                               = 0
    shmdt(0x2b66af7d8000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b66b0018000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b66af3a8000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b66af638000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b66af758000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b66aff78000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b66af6d8000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b66afed8000)                   = 0
    close(4)                                = 0
    close(5)                                = 0
    exit_group(0)                           = ?
    Process 12420 detached
```

and in the buggy run, I see:

```
    socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 9
    setsockopt(9, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
    setsockopt(9, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
    setsockopt(9, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [65536], 4) = 0
    setsockopt(9, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [65536], 4) = 0
    fcntl(9, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
    fcntl(9, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)               = 0
    connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(50825), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.10.10.251")}, 16) = 0
    write(9, "12345\0", 6)                  = 6
    write(9, "15  NORMAL_EXITING\0", 19)    = 19
    read(9, "\0", 1)                        = 1
    close(9)                                = 0
    futex(0x2b74f03659d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 13135, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    futex(0x2b74f01649d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 13132, NULL) = 0
    close(6)                                = 0
    close(7)                                = 0
    shmdt(0x2b74efce0000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b74f03e0000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b74efbe0000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b74f0480000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b74ef8b0000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b74efb40000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b74efc60000)                   = 0
    shmdt(0x2b74f0520000)                   = 0
    close(4)                                = 0
    close(5)                                = 0
    exit_group(0)                           = ?
    Process 13129 detached
```

As you can see, although both of them say `exit_group(0)`, the latter says a resource is temporarily unavailable.

Any thought on that?

Comment: It looks like the second example hasn't closed all the sockets and might be holding a lock on the process (notice the discrepancy in `close(n)`. Maybe try running the process in a `screen` session...

Comment: I found this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370489 related to mine. In the answer there is a time out parameter but I don't know how to set that. Is it possible to change the kernel parameters for that? I don't have access to the source code of the binary