# Resource temporarly unavalible - MSG_DONTWAIT flag

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, networking

I am using tcp socket server and client in c.
Using AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM and IPPROTO_TCP

**My send function in client side**

```
sent_now = send(sockId, buffer + sent_total, len - sent_total, MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

When I send MSG up to size like 20K-40KB, It works fine.
When I send MSG  up to size like 365K (Thats what I need), I receive the following error in the server Side: Resource temporarily unavailable!

**My receive function in server side**

totalRecvMsgSize = recieve ( clntSocket, Buffer, RCVBUFSIZE , MSG_DONTWAIT);

I send int data type.

How can I receive all the array in one send and receive operation?

***old post***

There is a post [What can cause a “Resource temporarily unavailable” on sock send() command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370489/what-can-cause-a-resource-temporarily-unavailable-on-sock-send-command), where Davide Berra says that

> That's because you're using a non-blocking socket and the output
>   buffer is full.
>
> From the send() man page
>
> When the message does not fit into  the  send  buffer  of  the 
>   socket,    send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed
>   in non-block-    ing I/O mode.  In non-blocking mode it  would  return
>   EAGAIN  in  this    case.
>
> EAGAIN is the error code tied to "Resource temporarily unavailable"
>
> Consider using select() to get a better control of this behaviours

***My question is:***

***1) How can I receive all the array in one send and receive operation? ***

***2) does select() help me in this array size?***

***3) Can I change the buffer sizes and how?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a stream socket, you use a loop on [`send()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html), and `MSG_WAITALL` on [`recv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html).

Consider these helper functions:

```
/* Receive the entire buffer.
 * Returns 0 if success, nonzero errno otherwise.
*/
static int recv_all(const int sockfd, void *buffer, const size_t len)
{
    ssize_t n;

    n = recv(sockfd, buffer, len, MSG_WAITALL);
    if (n == 0)
        return errno = EPIPE; /* Other end will not send more data */
    else
    if (n == -1)
        return errno;
    else
    if (n < -1)
        return errno = EIO;   /* Should never occur */
    else
    if (n != (ssize_t)len)
        return errno = EINTR; /* Interrupted, or sender goofed */
    else
        return 0;
}

/* Send the entire buffer.
 * Returns 0 if success, nonzero errno otherwise.
*/
static int send_all(const int sockfd, const void *buffer, const size_t len)
{
    const char       *pos = (const char *)buffer;
    const char *const end = (const char *)buffer + len;
    ssize_t           n;

    while (pos < end) {

        n = send(sockfd, pos, (size_t)(end - pos), 0);
        if (n > 0)
            pos += n; 
        else
        if (n != -1)
            return errno = EIO;
        else
            return errno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Found this solution one hour ago and it works great. I have another problem but this is for a different question.

Comment: probably the line `return errno = EPIPE;` is wrong and you should use `return errno == EPIPE;`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't reliably achieve this. You can always code up your own `sendall` and `recvall` functions that set the socket to blocking, then repeatedly call `send` (/`recv`) until all the data is sent/received. (*Usually* a single `send` call with a blocking socket will result in all data being sent in one operation but there are situations [signal after some data transferred, for example] that will cause an early return, so you should not depend on that.)
2. You can use `select` to achieve the same thing with non-blocking sockets but it makes buffer management more complex. You need to keep track of where you are in each buffer / how much data remains, and when `select` reports that a socket is "readable" or "writable" make a new attempt to send/receive at the appropriate place in the respective buffer.
3. Yes, you can make the buffer sizes whatever you like, but if you mean "can I set the system buffer sizes somehow to avoid this?" then no, there is no way to configure the system to make this work 100% reliably without additional code. TCP does not maintain message boundaries. Your protocol must impose boundaries atop the logical stream TCP provides.