# How can I fix Resource temporarily unavailable error in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

Here's an error log:

```
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
        thread 'arbiter:724dcce3-b3b3-4523-8b02-3b2e9fa035dd:actix-net-worker-62' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
```

Here's my server setup:

```
let _ = server::new(move || {
        App::with_state()
            // Enable logger
            .middleware(middleware::Logger::default())
            .resource("/default", |r| HttpResponse::Ok)
    })
    .bind(&localhost_port)
    .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Can not bind to {}", &localhost_port))
    .start();
```

I did look at another [actix](https://github.com/actix) example which [includes](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/basics/src/main.rs#L137):

```
.shutdown_timeout(0)    // <- Set shutdown timeout to 0 seconds (default 60s)
```

but don't think it fix the issue for me.

Locally it runs OK, but this errors shows up when I execute a binary on Ubuntu `16.04`.

Here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14370767 that suggests to set a `setting a send timeout with the SO_SNDTIMEO socket option`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue isn't related to Rust (or Actix). Your problem is that some other program is already listening on the same port that you are trying to bind to. You need to identify which program it is, for example with:

```
sudo netstat -an --program | grep $PORT
```

(replacing `$PORT` with your port number), then kill that program or use another port.